# How to pass surrounding scope to function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope

Is it possible to 'pass the surrounding scope' to a function defined outside of the scope?

I was trying to make my angular js directives easier to read, and I was wondering if passing the surrounding scope was possible in Javascript. I would like `a` to have access to the `local` variable:

```
var a, b;

a = function() {
  return console.log('local = ', local);
};

b = function() {
  var local;
  local = 1;
  return a();
};

b();
```

Comment: If the variable is defined in the outer scope, `linkedFn` will have access to it, not seeing a variable called `$rootScope` anywhere in this code though, just a string ... ?

Comment: @Damon, that was angular specific, my bad. I have fixed the example to use pure JS.

Comment: there's no `linkFn` or `$rootScope` in the code you've provided ... in the code you've provided it looks like you want function a to have access to var local that is declared inside function b. there is no "surrounding" scope - except the global scope, so perhaps you want var local to be  `window.local` or simply `local` with no preceding `var` when "declared" in function b. But this is all a guess as your text and code seem to be unconnected - alternatively pass `local` as an argument to function a and have function a accept an argument, call it local

Comment: declare `local` in the outermost scope in which it needs to be used (move the `var local` up a level)

Comment: @JaromandaX, sorry about that. Fixed.